# Numbering depth in appendix

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

I have a long (mathematical) document with parts, sections, subsections and paragraphs. The theorems etc. in the parts are numbered

```
Theorem 1.2.3
```

where the first number corresponds to the `section`, the second number to the `subsection` and the third to the number of the theorem, example, etc.

In the appendix (and only in the appendix), I will only use sections, no subsections. By default, a lemma in the appendix is numbered as

```
Lemma A.0.1
```

for the first lemma in the first appendix. I would like to suppress the `subsection` number (only in the appendix), so that the first lemma in the first appendix is numbered as

```
Lemma A.1
```

I have tried to add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` after the `\appendix` command, but nothing changed.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesection.\arabic{theorem}}` after you've started you Appendix.

Comment: @Werner Almost works. The numbering is carried on from the last section (presumably because the Lemma number is dependent on the subsection counter). So, if the last section had 4 lemmas, then the first lemma of the appendix is numbered `Lemma A.5`. Do I need to redefine all my theorems/lemmas/etc.? Is that possible outside of the preamble?

Comment: Try loading the package `chngcntr` and putting `\counterwithin{theorem}{section}` after `\appendix`.

Comment: Obviously, if `theorem` is not your counter, replace it with the one you-re using, e.g. `lemma`.

Comment: @karlkoeller That works, thank you very much. Could you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your lemmas use the `theorem` counter as in the MWE below, you can insert the line

```
\counterwithin{theorem}{section}
```

just after the `\appendix` command. Note that you have to load the package `chngcntr` to be able to use `\counterwithin`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % just for the example

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{1st section}
\subsection{1st subsection}
\begin{lemma}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{lemma}

\section{2nd section}
\subsection{2nd subsection}
\begin{lemma}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{lemma}

\appendix
\counterwithin{theorem}{section}
\section{Appendix section}
\begin{lemma}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Output

> [image]

If your lemmas use a different counter, e.g. `lemma`, you have to change the mentioned line to, e.g.

```
\counterwithin{lemma}{section}
```