# Numbering depth in appendix when the appendix is a separate file from the main

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

I saw the thread [Numbering depth in appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132045/numbering-depth-in-appendix)

but unfortunately, I don't know how to adjust the code to fit this into the case where my appendix is a separate tex file in my project, as is shown in the screenshots below.

The main tex file is Thesis.tex while app1.tex is the appendix file. The theorem in appendix is displayed as Theorem A.0.1. But I want Theorem A.0.1 to become Theorem A.1. I don't know how to make the commands

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin{theorem}{section}
```

work in my case. Like, where should I add them? I have try many places but they are not working as expected. Or do you have any other solutions?

In Thesis.tex

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}


\appendix
\include{app1}

\end{document}
```

In app1.tex

```
\chapter{The Data on Cows}
\label{data.app}

\begin{theorem}

\end{theorem}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post images of code, but add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and [format your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192).

Comment: @dexteritas I hope this is good now?

Comment: It is better, but your example is not working. `osudissert96` is no standard class, use `book` instead. Remove bibliography as it is not important for this problem (we don't have your `bibfile`). Add `app2.tex` or remove `\include{app2}`.

Comment: @dexteritas Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- corrected the code to a MWE
- use `\counterwithin{theorem}{chapter}` (`chapter` instead of `section`, as you use a book-like class)

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}


\appendix
\counterwithin{theorem}{chapter}
\chapter{The Data on Cows}
\label{data.app}

\begin{theorem}
bla
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```